# Input from console window in game

Tags: c++, console-application, keyboard-input

when you want to input in console window and you hold a key down for a moment, the output is displayed but after a bit of some lag. for example, in any type of common text editors you would see the same result. is there anyway to get a direct input for console games?  I'm currently using _getch() to read the keyboard input and _kbhit to check if a key was pressed in game loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure about the situation which you are describing, but if I remember correctly, console applications has buffering for keyboard inputs. You may want to flush the keyboard inputs for immediate response.

Comment: cout.flush() or put an endl after it? I tried but i don't see any difference.